# Secondary screen rotation unavailable in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, xfce, hdmi

I have a laptop with Xubuntu 15.04. I want to use my old Samsung full-hd TV as a secondary **portrait** monitor. I connected it using HDMI and it works, but in *Settings > Screen* there's no option in the *Rotation* menu for that screen. Note that for the laptop screen it's there and it works!

[image: No rotation options for the HDMI screen]
[image: Rotation options works for the laptop screen]

Going ommand line, `xrandr` names my secondary screen as `HDMI-1-0`, so I tried:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --rotation left
xrandr: output HDMI-1-0 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

Why? Is it a problem with the open source drivers for the integrated graphic card (Intel)?